# Unable to extract fields form log line containing a mix of JSON and non-JSON data using grok in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-logback-encoder

I am running a couple of Spring Boot applications in Docker containers. Since I don't want to log to files, I am instead logging to the console and then using [logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) to forward the logs to Logstash. I am using [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder) to log all logs from the application in JSON format.

Apart from these, there are also some logs (console outputs) which are made by the docker container before starting the Spring Boot application. These are not in JSON format.

To both of these, Logspout appends metadata (container name, container id, etc) before sending to Logstash. Below are my example logs in both formats.

1. Direct from container (no JSON)

> <14>1 2016-12-01T12:58:20Z 903c18d47759 com-test-myapp 31635
>   - - Setting active profile to test

2. Application logs (in JSON format)

> <14>1 2016-12-01T13:08:13Z 903c18d47759 com-test-myapp 31635
>   - - {"@timestamp":"2016-12-01T13:08:13.651+00:00","@version":1,"message":"Some
>   log message goes
>   here","logger_name":"com.test.myapp.MyClass","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"HOSTNAME":"903c18d47759"}

Below is my Logstash grok configuration.

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => "logspout-syslog-tcp"
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "logspout-syslog-tcp" {
    grok {
      match => {
        "message" => [
          "<%{NUMBER:syslogPriority}>1 %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:eventTimestamp} %{BASE16NUM:containerId} %{DATA:containerName} %{NUMBER:containerPort} - - %{DATA:jsonLog}",
          "<%{NUMBER:syslogPriority}>1 %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:eventTimestamp} %{BASE16NUM:containerId} %{DATA:containerName} %{NUMBER:containerPort} - - %{DATA:regularLog}"
        ]
      }
    }

    json {
        source => "jsonLog"
        target => "parsedJson"
        remove_field=>["jsonLog"]
    }

    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "level" => "%{[parsedJson][level]}"
        "thread" => "%{[parsedJson][thread_name]}"
        "logger" => "%{[parsedJson][logger_name]}"
        "message" => ["%{[parsedJson][message]}"]
      }
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Based on this, I was hoping to have each field in JSON available as a filter in Elasticsearch/Kibana. But I am not able to get the value of those fields. It shows up in Kibana as below:
[image]

I am not sure what I am missing here. How should I go about extracting the fields from JSON? Also, is the grok filter correct for handling both JSON and non-JSON logs?

Thanks,
Anoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `%{DATA:jsonLog}` part. The DATA pattern, `.*?`, is not greedy (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/nVSZbC/1)), so it won't grab anything and won't create the `jsonLog` field. You'll need to use the `GREEDYDATA` pattern instead.

See http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result to test your patterns.

Comment: Thanks @baudsp for the response. That was indeed the issue.
I am now able to parse the fields within the JSON. But, the same pattern matches for both JSON and non-JSON type. Next step is for me to figure out how to distinguish them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Anoop Glad I could help.

Comment: Managed to get it fixed. I used the a single grok match which creates a single field. Then I use the same field to parse the JSON.. Below are the relevant pieces of configuration.

`grok {
      match => {
        "message" => [
            "<%{NUMBER:syslogPriority}>1 %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:eventTimestamp} %{BASE16NUM:containerId} %{DATA:containerName} %{NUMBER:containerPort} - - %{GREEDYDATA:log}",
        ]
      }
    }
json {
        source => "log"
        target => "parsedJson"
    }

    if [parsedJson] {
     // Put code to parse fields from JSON
    }
`